# How to keep allocating memory until 3GB have been allocated in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, memory-leaks

I really hope that my title is correct, but let me explain exactly what I mean by the title.
I need to write a program that creates an `byte Array` with the size of 1MB and add it in an `ArrayList<byte[]>`.

I need to be doing that until I have added the amount of 3GB. Also after every allocation I should use `Thread.sleep(20)`.

I think I understand how the implementation should look like, but I'm having difficulties with calculating that exact 1MB and the variables.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MemLeak
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int maxSize = 3221225472; // 3GB in bytes
        int startSize = 0;

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1048576]; // 1MB in bytes
        ArrayList<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

        while (startSize != maxSize) {
            list.add(byteArray);
            Thread.sleep(20);
            startSize = startSize + 1048576;

        }

    }
}
```

In my case I have thought that the number of elements in an byte Array equals to size in bytes, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
The Variable int `maxSize = 3221225472` is also out of int range.

Could someone give me some pointers?
Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Have you run the code? What happened?

Comment: I have, I get the compilation error due to the value: 3221225472  being out of int range.

Comment: Then make it a `long`

Comment: that value is also out of range for long

Answer (score 0):

If the byte array declaration is moved inside the loop then each iteration allocates 1MB. Do this 3072 times to allocate 3GB of total space. No need to keep track of maxSize.

If the goal is for the ArrayList + its data to consume exactly 3GB of memory, that will be more difficult, because the ArrayList class consumes its own space outside of your data, and it also does its own internal memory management, so it might go from less than to more than 3GB when it needs to create more internal space. Have a look at the source code of ArrayList.add() to see what I mean.

Comment: Are you saying that the loop right now allocates 1MB? I doubt that, there is only 1 array and 3072 references to that same array.

Comment: Should I be then creating new arrays of the same size and adding them to the ArrayList? No idea how would that work then because the variables should be named differently then 3072 times.

Comment: @luk2302 thank you for that. I had assumed that the array allocation would be moved to inside the loop but forgot to clarify that (editing my answer now). @Smokus each iteration of the loop can add an element that is a 1MB array. No need for 3072 variables. Thinking about it in reverse: an ArrayList with elements that are each a 1MB array, the first element can be accessed with `list.get(0)`, the second with `list.get(1)` and so on. To create such a list of 1MB byte arrays, call `list.add(new byte[1048576])` 3072 times, which I thought was what you were asking. Hope I'm not mistaking that!